# spark java: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, apache-spark

While running the below code in Spark Java (`local`), I get the error:

```
at Datahub.run(Datahub.java:96)
    at Datahub.main(Datahub.java:64)
***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class***
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Logic to read csv and save it in parquet format.

```
public class Datahub implements Serializable{

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")

    private transient SparkConf sparConf;
    private transient  JavaSparkContext sparkContext;
    private transient SQLContext SQLContext;

    public Datahub(){
        sparConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Datahub").setMaster("local");
        sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparConf);
        SQLContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/tools/spark");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Datahub job = new Datahub();
        job.run("a","b");
     }

    public void run(String t, String u)
    {

        JavaRDD<String> pairRDD =  sparkContext.textFile("C:/temp/L1_result.csv");
        JavaPairRDD<String,String> rowJavaRDD = pairRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {


        public Tuple2<String,String> call(String rec) {

             String[] tokens = rec.split(";");
             String[] vals = new String[tokens.length];
             for(int i= 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
                       vals[i] =tokens[i];
        }
                return new Tuple2<String, String>(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        } });

        Dataset<Row> fundDF = SQLContext.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD.values(), funds.class);
        fundDF.printSchema();
        fundDF.show();
        fundDF.write().option("mergeschema", true).parquet("C:/test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the below changes:

```
 funds b0 = new funds(); b0.setK("k0"); b0.setSomething("sth0");
 funds b1 = new funds(); b1.setK("k1"); b1.setSomething("sth1"); 
 List<funds> data = new ArrayList<funds>();
 data.add(b0); data.add(b1);
 Dataset<Row> fundDf = SQLContext.createDataFrame(data, funds.class); 
 fundDf.printSchema();
 fundDf.write().option("mergeschema", true).parquet("C:/test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file and convert it to the bean class **funds** as follows:

```
Dataset<funds> fundsDF = SQLContext.read().csv("C:/temp/L1_result.csv").as(Encoders.bean(funds.class));
```